# Conditional formatting in Excel: Referencing entire table column

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting, conditional-formatting, microsoft-excel-2016, rules

In Excel I am trying to apply conditional formatting to an entire table column (it should be automatically applied, when new rows are added into the table)

However, the conditional formatting rules don't seem to work in that way:

- Each time I create such rule, the column reference gets translated into an absolute cell reference, which is wrong, because it doesn't scale as the table grows.

`=DeptSales[Sales Amount]` gets translated to `=$D$2:$D$34`

- For some reason even when editing the rule, I am unable to use the column reference, an error gets displayed.

`=WENN(ISTLEER(D2:D34);FALSCH;ZÄHLENWENN(Name_in_system;D2:D34)=0)` works, `=WENN(ISTLEER(DeptSales[Sales Amount]);FALSCH;ZÄHLENWENN(Name_in_system;DeptSales[Sales Amount])=0)` results in an error (shown below)

*- `Name_in_System` is a list and it is not the cause of the error

How to reference the entire column in a conditional formatting rule?

[image: Conditional formatting rules manager]
[image: Editing a conditional rule]
[image: Error when editing a conditional rule]

Comment: you cannot use ISTLEER(DeptSales[Sales Amount])) for a range you can use one cell at a time in conditional formatting, if you explain the condition, if also does not work you have to write a different formula

Comment: This function in the rule editor does what I expected `=WENN(ISTLEER(D2);FALSCH;ZÄHLENWENN(Name_in_system;D2)=0)`. However, I still didn't figure out how how to avoid the absolute definition of the cell range `=$D$2:$D$34`. It gets broken into smaller ranges, when copying/pasting rows.